# Destroy resources created by ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

> **What specific syntax needs to be used in order to successfully destroy all resources that were created by the `devenvironment` deployment group in the code below?**

##### The Context:

A collection of resources are created in Azure when the following command is run:

```
az deployment group create --name devenvironment --resource-group myResourceGroupDev --template-file C:\path\to\my.template.json --parameters C:\path\to\my.parameters.json --verbose
```

##### The Problem:

The problem we are having is that the following command leaves all the created resources intact in Azure:

```
az deployment group delete --name devenvironment --resource-group myResourceGroupDev --verbose
```

All that this `az deployment group delete` command does is delete the wrapper `devenvironment` that associates the resources that were created using the `az deployment group create` command above.  This `az deployment group delete` command fails to have any effect on the actual resources that were created.

##### Desired Result:

What we want is a command that will result in destroying all of the resources that were created by the `az deployment group create` command.

We want a command like `terraform destroy` that destroys all the resources that were created in an ARM deployment, but using the `az` cli.

What specific syntax will bring about our desired result?

Comment: Microsoft should add destroy feature with Bicep, atleast.

Answer (score 4):

We don't have any direct cmdlet to delete all the resources that were deployed in a specific deployment using the arm template.

You can use the below Azure CLI Cmdlets or PowerShell cmdlets which will delete the resources that were deployed using the arm template.

To test this in our local environment, we have created a webapp & app service plan using arm template. Using the below cmdlets we are able to delete those resources successfully.

**Here are the Azure CLI cmdlets:**

```
resourcelist=$(az deployment group  show --resource-group '<rgName>' --name '<deploymentName>' --query "properties.outputResources[].id" -o tsv)
for resource in $resourcelist; do az resource delete --ids $resource; done
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference :**

[image]

**Here are the PowerShell cmdlets:**

```
$resourcelist=Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentOperation -ResourceGroupName '<resourceGroupName>' -Name '<deploymentName>'
foreach ($resource in $resourcelist){
    if( $resource.TargetResource -ne $null){
         Remove-AzResource -ResourceId $resource.TargetResource -Force 
         Write-Output "Resource got delete successfully"$resource.TargetResource
  }
}
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: How do you suggest preventing `ResourceNotFound` errors thrown in your CLI version of the command above?  I have been looking into `az resource list`, but a lot of string splitting seems necessary and I am concerned that the result might not be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler solution to this. But it does require you destroy everything in the resource group. But then that is the only way Bicep can manage "owning" the resources it creates, is by owning the entire resource group.

I'm doing AKS so if I have a bicep file that defines that and I can do a deployment like so.

```
az deployment group create \
  --resource-group ${RESOURCEGROUP} \
  --name ${DEPLOYMENT} \
  --template-file ./aks.bicep \
  --parameters "./aks.parameters.json" \
  --mode Complete
```

Then to destroy it takes 2 steps. One to remove resources using --mode Complete. And one to delete the deployment group name.

```
# -- apply empty bicep template file to wipe out the resource group contents
az deployment group create \
  --resource-group ${RESOURCEGROUP} \
  --name ${DEPLOYMENT} \
  --template-file ./empty.bicep \
  --mode Complete 

# -- And now we remove the deployment name 
#    (that appears to have no real value or effect anyway)
az deployment group delete \
  --resource-group ${RESOURCEGROUP} \
  --name ${DEPLOYMENT}
```

It's ugly but I've not found any other useful, foolproof way to fully destroy resources created with bicep.