Issues with Deleting Azure Deployment created with Azure Template Using CLI Commands
I have created Azure infrastructure using an ARM template for a resource group with the Azure CLI command:
az deployment group create --resource-group demo --template-file main.json --parameters parameters.json --name serviceName
I tried deleting this deployment, as I would with terraform destroy, using the az deployment group delete --name serviceName and az deployment sub delete --name serviceName commands. However, it does nothing and returns no errors. When I check, the resources are still there. Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong?
I need to delete the resource using similar command as terraform destroy

I have just test as @D1_1 says, az deployment group delete -g my-rg -n my-deployment only delete the deployment history record named my-deployment at my-rg resource group. not actually delete the resources. and seems not directly way  to delete all the resources deployed by arm template.

here is a similar question as you, and which provide some useful command to achieve your goal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229433/destroy-resources-created-by-arm-template-deployment

@wenbo without the template file it will delete all resources in the resource group. That’s the closest to delete possible. Might be worth MS having a feature to enable deletion by template file. Thanks for your response.

The Azure CLI currently does not have a command equivalent to Terraform's terraform destroy.
The az deployment group delete is used to delete the deployment record from a resource group's deployment history (i.e. the entry marked in the image below). The deployed resources are unaffected.

Image: resource group deployment history shown in the "deployments" tab.
The az deployment sub delete and az deployment mg delete provide the same functionality as az deployment group delete, at the subscription and management group scope respectively.

I am surprised this was the case, so apparently it only removes this from history, as there is a limit of 800 . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-history-deletions?tabs=azure-powershell

Correct, Azure makes sure that you do not go over this limit at the resource group and subscription scope. This is not the case for deployments at management group scope, you need to manage these yourself.
